# Кружат или кружатся?

Tags: стилистика

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сказать: "Кружат в хороводе"? Или это будет ошибкой, и правильно "кружатся"? Или без разницы? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Словари обычно не проводят строгого различия между ситуациями употребления этих слов (если оставить в стороне вариант использования глагола "кружить /кого-л., что-л./" как переходного), но я вариант "кружить" - стилистически и в интересах большей информативности речи - предпочёл бы в случае движения по окружности (человека в хороводе или по городу), а вариант "кружиться" - при движении вокруг оси (дисков или пары людей в вальсе). "Кружиться" в этом вращательном смысле может хоровод в целом - на некой лужайке и т. п.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **кружатся в хороводе, в вальсе.** Это танец кружит танцоров,  а танцоры кружатся. Например: Вихрем **закружит белый танец**.

**КРУЖИТЬСЯ,** 5. Делать, описывать круги на лету. Орлы кружатся высоко в небе. Над городом кружились самолёты.**КРУЖИТЬ,** 2. =Кружиться (5 зн.). В небе кружит ястреб. Самолёт кружит над аэродромом перед посадкой.

Таким образом кружить  (в значении кружиться)  ―  это только **описывать круги в воздухе, частное значение.**

Comment: Это не только о _воздушных_ кругах. Вот подборка нескольких десятков литературных цитат, среди которых не менее трети составляют случаи сухопутного "кружения": https://wikivox.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Вообще говоря, кружить (неперех) - это "рисовать"  круги, то есть двигаться по круговой траектории. Часто по воздуху, но также по воде, по лесу  - это в прямом смысле, возможны также переносные значения. Но "кружить в вальсе, в хороводе" - неточное выражение, поэтому разговорный стиль.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим в словарь:

> - КРУЖИ́ТЬ, кружу́, кру́жишь и кружи́шь; несов.
>
>   1. перех. Заставлять что-, кого-л. двигаться по кругу, сообщать чему-л. кругообразное движение. [Нина] танцевала с Олегом. Олег
>        уверенно и спокойно кружил ее крупное, сильное тело. Фадеев, Молодая
>        гвардия. Ветер проносился над площадью, кружа мусор, роняя и вновь
>        подхватывая длинные --- стебли. Березко, Ночь полководца.
>   2. То же, что кружиться (во 2 знач.). На бледном небе ястреб кружит, Чертя за кругом плавный круг. Блок, Возмездие. Он старался ни о чем не
>        думать, только вести самолет, кружить и кружить без конца, пока не
>        появятся, наконец, на поляне люди. Саянов, Небо и земля.
>   3. Двигаться извилистым путем, часто меняя направление, блуждая, плутая в поисках чего-л. Долго кружили по городу Райский и Полина
>        Карповна. И. Гончаров, Обрыв. [Метелица] прошел еще несколько
>        переулков, кружа возле церкви и, наконец, уперся в крашеный забор
>        поповского сада. Фадеев, Разгром. ||Делать многочисленные повороты,
>        изгибы (о дороге, тропинке). Тропа в лесу часто кружит и делает мелкие
>        извилины. Арсеньев, По Уссурийской тайге.
>   4. Взметать снег, пыль и т. п. (о вьюге, метели и т. п.); мести. Кружила метель; тусклые фонари, залепленные снегом, почти вовсе не
>        освещали улицы. Гайдар, Школа.
> - КРУЖИ́ТЬСЯ, кружу́сь, кру́жишься и кружи́шься; несов.
>
>   1. Двигаться по кругу, кругообразно. Кружиться в вальсе. Пенные бурлящие водовороты кружились в омуте. Пермитин, Раннее утро. Когда
>        она [ворона] взмахивала крыльями ---, от крыла отделялись перья; и
>        вскоре одно перо выпало и, кружась винтом, медленно --- падало на
>        землю. Вс. Иванов, Бог Матвей. ||Поворачиваться вокруг своей оси;
>        вращаться. И бежит, бежит лошадка вдоль ольховой просеки. Даль кружит.
>        И для порядка кружатся колесики. Недогонов, Флаг над сельсоветом.
>        ||Беспорядочно передвигаться; метаться. [Жеребята] кружились по
>        стойлу, тыкались из угла в угол, друг в друга. А. Кожевников, Живая
>        вода. || перен. Разг. Постоянно находиться где-л., около кого-л.
>        [Стогов:] И тут же этот Лузгин кружится ---. Почему это к вам
>        присосался Лузгин? М. Горький, Фальшивая монета. || перен. Разг. Быть
>        в постоянных хлопотах, суете. Писать тебе посланье Мне было недосуг
>        ---. От утра до утра Два года все кружился Без дела в хлопотах. Пушкин, Городок.
>   2. Делать, описывать круги на лету. Распластав свои могучие крылья, они [орлы] парили, описывая большие круги.--- Некоторые из них
>        кружились так высоко, что едва были заметны. Арсеньев, По Уссурийской
>        тайге. Над городом высоко кружились германские самолеты. А. Н.
>        Толстой, Восемнадцатый год. ||Виться в воздухе (о снеге, пыли и т.
>        п.). За зеркальными окнами столовой кружились ---, как белые мотыльки,
>        крупные хлопья снега. Морозов. Повести моей жизни. Летит с тополей
>        веселый и легкий пух, кружится над улицами и падает на крыши.
>        Горбатов, Непокоренные.
>   3. Разг. То же, что кружить (в 3 знач.). — Человек — не иголка, найдем. Он теперь в этих местах [в степи] кружится. Чехов, Степь.
>        [Мальчик] попал в Краков и запутался в нем. Он долго кружился по
>        улицам города и все не мог выбраться на простор поля. М. Горький,
>        Сергей Есенин. Я даже не мог заметить в наступавшей ночной темноте,
>        идет ли моя речка прямо или кружится. Морозов, Повести моей жизни.
>   4. То же, что кружить (в 4 знач.). За окном буйно кружилась, выла и свистела вьюга, бросая в стекла снегом. М. Горький, Жизнь Клима
>        Самгина.

Таким образом, стилестически нейтральный вариант - *кружиться в хороводе*.

Answer (score 0):

Как и в большинстве случаев с возвратной частицей "СЯ"
Если кто-то (что-то) кого-то (что-то), то кружит,
если сам себя (или самостоятельно), то кружитСЯ.
Причем, если речь идет о вращении вокруг своей оси, то - крутит или крутится.
Например:
ветер кружит снежинки;
снежинка кружится;
самолет кружится (но крутится в штопоре);
кружится зимняя вьюга;
волчок крутится. Мальчики кружат девочек в хороводе. Танцоры кружатся в хороводе.